# WhatsApp with Mac Catalina

Tags: macos, gatekeeper, catalina

After upgrade in Mac OS 10.15, WhatsApp would not open due to security check failure. In preference, the "Open Anyway" does not seem to work. Any workaround pls? Thanks

Comment: Is Whatsapp up to date?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found it. Use terminal to temporarily disable the security with sudo spctl --master-disable. Then restore with -enable